# Visually show input data from attribute table on map

Tags: qgis

I have 8500+ point-locations in QGIS, all with unique ID numbers, showing on my map; however, the unique ID numbers are not displayed.

Is there any way to filter this so that the ID numbers are present next to the point (all points at the same time)?

See pictures for clarifications.

[image]

https://i.ibb.co/3kLqnvY/avs-id.png

Comment: Please provide your pictures on this focused Q&A site via the Picture button rather than as links.  I've done one and will leave you to do the other.

Comment: The term you are looking for is "label" - have a look at the Labels tab in the Layer Properties dialog and the Label tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean "labeling" your features you have to check the given **layer's properties** :

Right-click on your layer in the layer manager and then :
"**Labels - Label with :**" and choose the attribute you want to display (**avs_id** ?)

You have then a lot of options available to fine tune the labeling behavior.